# How to call the python program in update mode using pre-buid program?

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio, computer-vision, argparse

I have been following the "Making an Emotion-Aware Music Player" tutorial and everything was works fine until running the main program in update. 
I searched for "argparse " in tutorials and found nothing about this method.

I have a very little knowledge about python so that could anyone please explain me how run the main program in update mode and where should type the following code.

[source page: Making an Emotion-Aware Music Player](http://www.paulvangent.com/2016/06/30/making-an-emotion-aware-music-player/)

> Once the file is downloaded, call the main program in “update mode” like this:
>   ~

```
#To activate update mode, pass the --update flag
python <filename.py> --update

#To get help, use the -h or --help flag
python <filename.py> -h
python <filename.py> --help
```

When I ran the above code in Command prompt it gave me a error, which says there is no XML file. But as for the main program it should create XML if there wasn't.

I'm using Visual studio 2015 with python 2.7

Comment: Have you read through that tutorial, including the comments?  A quick glance indicates that it needs two `xml` files, one that you download from somewhere, and one that it can generate with the `--update`.  A question on that blog might be more productive than here, since it's dealing with a specific program rather than Python in any general sense.

Comment: Yes, I red the tutorial. But it did not give clear instruction about executing --update .
My problem is how to execute --update to create trained_emoclassifier.xml.

Comment: Do you have a `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` file?  If you don't have a `trained_emoclassifier.xml`, it looks like it will give the print warning, but will then create the file if you specify the `--update` flag.

Comment: I have the _frontalface_default.xml. I do not know how to execute --update